# heatmap data visualization with categorical count and time in r

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am trying to create a simple heatmap that has a list of non-redundant category character (heat$cat) on the y-axis and date/time as the x-axis. 
Two customization on the heat map 1) The headmap gradient reflect the frequency count of categories (heat$cat),e.g. 1-2=blue, 3 or above =dark; 2)The total frequency count of (heat$cat) should display on the right hand side of the heatmap.

Here is the dataset, thanks very much for your input!

```
cat<-c("A","A","A","C","D","E","E","E","F","F")
date<-c("05-05-2020","05-05-2020","05-05-2020","04-05-2020","05-05-2020","04-05-2020","03-05-2020","04-05-2020","04-05-2020","04-05-2020" )
date<-as.Date(format(date, format="%d-%m-%Y"))
heat<-cbind(cat,date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date format doesn't seem correct.. Anyway, you make it a factor, then use dplyr to group and fill in the zeros. Pipe it into ggplot and use geom_tile() for heatmap:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

date <- as.Date(date,"%d-%m-%Y")
data.frame(cat=cat,date=factor(date)) %>% 
count(cat,date,.drop=FALSE) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=date,y=cat,fill=n)) + geom_tile()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot! It works well. How would you suggest if I want to show the CAT with the highest count to be displayed on top? Eg. A>E>F>C>E. Thanks!

Comment: ggplot(aes(x=date,y=cat,fill=n)) ; try to keep to your question; this can be found in SO as well